# Onclose of a modal, how to get focus back to the interactive element clicked on? React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, web-development-server

on click of a button, a modal opens and once the modal closes, the focus should be back on the button for accessibility. I have tried using a ref and an id. Neither worked.

Carbon components are being used where we just directly call the `<Modal>` tag to create a modal.

Comment: Show your code, which library are you using?

Comment: create a codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to somehow add either an OnClick attribute to the button that closes the modal, or add an event listener.

```
<!-- OnClick Method -->
<h2>Hello</h2>
<button onClick={closeModal}>close</button>
<div>I am a modal</div>
```

or

```
<!-- Event Listener Method -->
<h2>Hello</h2>
<button id="close-modal">close</button>
<div>I am a modal</div>
....
<script>
    document.getElementById("close-modal").addEventListener("click", closeModal);
</script>
```

In the JS function that hooks up to the OnClick or event listener, you can set the focus using vanilla JS.

```
  function closeModal(){
     document.getElementById("ID-of-element-needing-focus").focus();
  }
```